# is it right way( safe) to assign post data value directly by name attibute value to a variable in php

Tags: php

i m working in PHP since one year, but now a days i got this way to assign post data value directly using name attribute . i m really curious to know the documentation about it.please refere me link regarding this .

i explain by example

here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
<input type="submit" name="doit" value="submit">
</form>
```

to get the post data i always use

```
$somevar=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
```

but now i see another way

```
$somevar= "userName";
```

i just want to know that is it safe n easy way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the PHP ini directive [`register_globals`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals).  Take a look at [Variables From External Sources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).  However, this directive defaults to "off" and you should probably leave it that way since it is deprecated in PHP 5.3.  You would still have to `mysql_real_escape_string()` it anyway.

You can also use [`import_request_variables()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php) to register the globals manually:

```
import_request_variables("p");
echo $userName;
```

[Using Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) on the PHP website gives you a good idea as to how it can be unsafe to automatically register HTTP variables as globals.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like to use an escape function. So I would stick with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

I've never seen any code where a variable has been assigned from a quoted value. The way I understand it, all you'd be doing is making `$somevar` contain a string `userName`

Comment: I completely agree with u sir, but i seen this method, that's why i fire this question.
even `register_globals` is off in php

Answer (score 0):

you can better use the below one

```
$somevar= $userName;
OR
$somevar= $_POST[userName];
```

Comment: i m not asking which one i have to use? i m asking that is it right way( 2'nd one)

Comment: sorry! i m just asking that hev u ven seen the method 1? if yes then provide me any documentation regarding that